# Configuring pep8 in Textmate

Tags: python, textmate, textmatebundles, pep8

Textmate has a Python PEP8 bundle that will run pep8 validation on your file.  How can I set it to do the equivalent of `pep8 --ignore=E501 my_file.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the pep8 bundle has added a feature to hide user-specified error codes.

http://github.com/ppierre/python-pep8-tmbundle